# Ember.js - Query inside component, Error: end called without begin

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember.js, I'm trying to query the store inside a component, like so:

```
let foo = this.get('store').query('bar', { foobar: this.get('barfoo') });
```

but keep getting an error as follows:

```
end called without begin at Backburner.end
```

Any idea why this could be happening?
Cheers

EDIT: Tried this on a route instead of a component, but the same error keeps occurring.

Comment: I think we'd need to see more code than that. Generally speaking, it is considered better practice to fetch your data within your route and pass it down to your component.

Comment: That line is inside a computed property. There's not much more to it right now

Comment: How are you trying to use `foo`?

Comment: I had the same issue in my tests when fetching data from a component in the init hook (it's generally a bad practice but there are some cases that getting the data from the route is simply not the best option). It only failed in tests, even using mirage :(. Not a clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone stumbling on this through google, this happens when you're trying to pass in an Object as a query param and `jQuery` fails to serialise it. Try passing in a primitive type instead.

Answer (score 3):

Computed properties do not handle promises (async calls) directly, and that's what `foo` will be set to until the promise resolves from the async call. If you want to set `foo` to the returned value from the query, you could do this in a function call and use `set('foo', returnValue)` to assign the value to `foo`.

That is a bit of an anti-pattern in Ember, which is why it is recommended to do the data loading and async calls in the route model because it is promise aware.

You could also look into returning a `DS.PromiseArray` like in this code example:

```
filter3: computed('ingredients.@each.vegetarian', function() {
  return DS.PromiseArray.create({
    promise: this.get('ingredients').then(ingredients => {
      return ingredients.filterBy('vegetarian');
    })
  });
})
```

More info:
https://emberigniter.com/guide-promises-computed-properties/